# Pass the value from View to the Mainwindow when the View is closed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have made a Usercontrol based on MVVM. A window(e.g. MainWindow.xaml) calls this Usercontrol, the View of this Usercontrol has a treeview with nodes, child nodes and buttons ('ok', etc...). The user selects a node in the treeview and press the "ok" button on the View. I could read the selected nodes of the treeview in the View.xaml.cs. I have created dependency properties in View.xaml.cs to save the selected treeview item. In the mainwindow.xaml.cs, I am instantiating my usercontrol and calling the dependency property e.g. usercontrol.value where value is the dependency property in the View. 
The overall idea is when user selects the treeview node and press ok, the view should be close and the value of the selected treeview item is paased to the Window.

**The problem is when I close the view the value of the dependency property get lost and null is returned to the Window**

I am new to WPF.

**Window.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <view:SystemExplorerView x:Name="MyView"></view:SystemExplorerView>
</Grid>
```

**Window.xaml.cs**

```
 public object m_myValue;
    public object myValue {
        get { return m_myValue; }
        set
        {
            m_myValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("myValue");
        }
    }
public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myValue = MyView.Value;
        }
```

**View.xaml.cs**

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(SystemExplorerView),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));
  public SystemExplorerView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
public object Value
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ValueProperty, value);

            }
        }
 private void OKbtnclk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Value = myTreeView.SelectedItem;
            Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
        }
```

Comment: the code is quite big, I have posted some of it please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Since your UserControl "based on MVVM", then you don't need to use dependency property. Store your data in ViewModel and operate with it!

Comment: If I store in ViewModel then how am I going to pass the property from ViewModel to the MainWindow, doesnt it breaks the MVVM rule? I am still learning this stuff

Comment: See C# MVVM Summary and Complete Example https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mvvm/4293/getting-started-with-mvvm#t=201708170709094382013

Comment: @Smallestearth Don't listen to every advice here on StackOverflow. Dependency properties are exactly the right approach for UserControls. A UserControl should generally not have any "own" view model. Instead you bind its dependency properties to view model properties when you instantiate the control.

Comment: What you probably want is a `Closing` event handler in your MainWindow, which simply calls `myValue = MyView.Value;` again. However, you might create a simple view model class, and bind the control's `Value` to a view model property (by a two-way binding). This the view model property would always hold the same value as the dependency property in the UserControl.

Comment: @Clemens sorry for the late reply, thank you very much. Your solution works. I will accept it as an answer, if you write the above comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may access the property in a `Closing` event handler:

```
<Window ... Closing="Window_Closing">
    ...
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    myValue = MyView.Value;
}
```